# Showing a specific cell each scroll back on UICollectionView

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, custom-cell

I'm trying to load a custom cell each time someone scrolls up/back on my UICollectionView then if a condition is met, allow that user to see the previous items in the UICollectionView / resume normal UICollectionView behavior.

I tried subtracting the current indexpath.row, but that isn't working and I can't wrap my head around what exactly the case needs to be to make it work.

I was able to successfully get the custom cell to render as the third item (2) in the UICollectionView (shown below), but can't figure out how to make it's index path 0 and start the collection view on index path 1.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

 if (indexPath.row == 2) {
    MyCustomCell *customCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"customCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return customCell;
}
else {
    PhotoCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"photo" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    _obj_IndexPath = indexPath;
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)_obj_IndexPath.row);

    _imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:200];
    _imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[_imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}
}
```

The goal is a normal UICollectionView functionality with "full-screen" cells that scroll vertically AND during a certain condition scrolling to the previous cell is limited to only one scroll back AND that cell has a special / custom view on top of the cell content.

Any help or ideas would be awesome. Thank you!

**I've updated my current code per comments below**

Comment: Quick question looking at the code. The conditional `indexPath.row == _obj_IndexPath.row - 1` seems a little off. Aren't those two variables pointing to the same object? If so, how could it ever be true?

Comment: Another potential code smell is the first line in the method. I believe weird things can happen when you call "dequeueResuableCellWithIdentifier` for the same index path twice in the same `cellForRowAtIndexPath` call. What happens when you move the `PhotoCell` setup logic in the "else" block near the bottom? (and of course all of the other relevant cell setup code after it)

Comment: Dan, yeah the condition never occurs. My logic is definitely off. I think I probably need something like: http://pastebin.com/hm1vkZYQ

Comment: Moving PhotoCell setup logic into the else statement == still works! Hadn't noticed any kooky stuff happening before but I'm running local/static arrays to populate. Good to solve that before all the network stuff is hooked up. Kudos on that. Logic problems still remain, going to keep trying.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the paste! I'm still having some trouble understanding the desired end result. Just to wrap my head around it more, what sort of UI are you trying to build? Endless scroll when scrolling up?

Comment: The goal is a normal UICollectionView functionality with "full-screen" cells that scroll vertically AND during a certain condition scrolling to the previous cell is limited to only one scroll back AND that cell has a special / custom view on top of the cell content. Hopefully that makes sense and also thank you for wanting to help :)

Comment: You could probably show the special cell as a supplementary view: http://www.appcoda.com/supplementary-view-uicollectionview-flow-layout/

I don't know if you want to limit what can cells exist in the cellForIndexPath: method or if it makes more sense to create a custom layout. http://blog.radi.ws/post/32905838158/sticky-headers-for-uicollectionview-using